# I can't access a css style with my javascript code. what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
#test{
background-color:#b10515; width=440px;
}
</style>
<script>
...
...
cell[k]=document.createElement('td'); 
var cont = document.createElement('a');
    switch(k){
        case 0:
           cont.innerHTML = jsArray[c].count;
           cell[k].className = 'test';
                break;
    }
```

Above is my code. In my speculation, cell[k] should have test css style since I set cell[k]

css class as test css. However, test css style was not attached to cell[k] when I run on Tomcat.

can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#test` is an *id selector*. You are setting a class. Use `.test` instead.

You also want `:` not `=` in your width rule.

Comment: my bet... I should use : then =.

Comment: Use `width: 440px;`

I suggest you take a CSS for beginners course, this will help you make the right selections and understand how the syntax is laid out, http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/